# My Dynamic Ajax site is overloaded with multiple getScript calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getscript

I have a dynamic website where all links grab new sections via an ajax request from other pages and replace the current section.

My problem comes in **two forms**. When I load a new div from an Ajax get request. Some sections need js files too. For example, one uses a particles.js as a canvas background. After I complete the ajax request I then getScript"js file" and it works. However if you move onto other sections that getScript is still running and now unbinded because that section is gone. If I go back to that section again I need to getScript again and now I'm running it twice. This can be very CPU and GPU intensive and slows down my site.

Things like css files are easy because I can create an if statement to load if its not already loaded, script tags are different because the Dom only loads once. Appending/removing the script to the head is useless because the site is entirely Ajaxed.

here is example of a script

```
//pricing.html
  $(".link-pricing").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#togglenav").collapse("hide");
    $("#main").load("../../damonmedek/home/pricing.html #main-pricing");
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
      if (settings.url === "../../damonmedek/home/pricing.html") {

        //Add CSS
        if (!$("link[href='../assets/css/home%20css/pricing%20css/particles-js.css']").length)
          $('<link href="../assets/css/home%20css/pricing%20css/particles-js.css" rel="stylesheet">').appendTo("head");
 

        //Remove CSS
        $('link[rel=stylesheet][href*="../assets/css/home%20css/best-carousel-slide.css"]').remove();
 


        //Add JS
        $.getScript("../assets/js/home/pricing%20js/modal%20popup.js", function () {});
        **$.getScript("../assets/js/home/pricing%20js/particles.js", function () {});**
        $.getScript("../assets/js/home/pricing%20js/pricing-animated%20heading.js", function () {});
        $.getScript("../assets/js/members%20js/ajax%20members-only.js", function () {});
        $.getScript("../assets/js/home/pricing%20js/app.js", function () {});
        $.getScript("../assets/js/members%20js/ajax%20members-only.js", function () {});
      }
    });
  });
```

How can I rebind page to js file, or stop getScript, or some smarter way to fix this problem?
Its not just cpu problems, duplicate getScripts can cause problems like posting twice on submit and weird stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

So this answer isn't as simple as I thought. Its involves event propagation which I encourage you too look up.
In order to grab the script just once its can't be through jquery but something like this.

````
function loadJSFile() {
  if ($('script[src="' + jsFile + '"]').length > 0) {
    //script exists
  } else {
    function loadScript(url, callback) {
      // adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.classList.add("example");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = url;

      // then bind the event to the callback function
      // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
      script.onreadystatechange = callback;
      script.onload = callback;

      // fire the loading
      body.appendChild(script);
    }
    var myPrettyCode = function () {
      // here, do what ever you want
    };
    loadScript(jsFile, myPrettyCode);
  }}```

Then you need to use a bubbling method to click on things. like a div that is flown in and out and flown in and out. the js file is only loaded once but you are clicking through the main div that is loaded on first page load. And into the div you flying in, that contains the ids and classes you have inside that div. kinda confusing I know. 

```$("#home-div").on('click', '#ajaxedInDiv', function (e) {
$("#ajaxedInDiv").attr("something");
}
````